# Clicking the method which is tested(in test class) redirect to metadata controller instead of original mvc controller(in .net). How to fix?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, model-view-controller, nunit

For the functions being tested in the unit test class(using Nunit), on clicking the function it redirects to metadata controller instead of the original controller. the original controller shows 0 reference for that function but the test is done successfully. Is there a way to show the actual reference so i can know how many test cases are written for a particular function?

Comment: How did you add reference of Web Project to test project?

Comment: add reference option on the project... tests are working fine btw with correct mocking